# iphoe-To get rectangular part of UIView and make a new view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a UIView with a image. I have used UIBezierPath and cropped a part of that view. Following image shows.

[image]

Now I want to have a new UIView object with frame as visible image. How can I do this. 
Please help. Thank You.

I used following to get image.

```
-(UIImage *)getImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [image retain];
    return [image autorelease];
}
```

But I get original full image not the one which is cropped. I got following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For Cut Rectangle Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(100 , 100, 50, 50);// set as you need
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

Use following method that return `UIImage` (*as You want size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Here You get `cropped` image and you can put it on you `newView` as `backGroungColor` such like  (also put image on `UIImageView` and add it io you `newView`)

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake("as YOu Need")];
self.tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:cropped]];
[self.view addSubView:newView];
```

Comment: I have a UIView on that image is cropped in curve shape. If i cut UIImage as you gave how will I get that shape?

Comment: if you have to done work of crop image then you follow my last code that i putted after cropping process.